# disabling the list item on sencha doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

this code here doesn't work for me. I'm still able to select the item after disabling it.
Ext.getCmp('CheckIn').getAt(2).setDisableSelection(true);
any reason why is this so?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? maybe is there a public config/method for that

Comment: I searched online and everyone is using that to disable the selection of a particular item on the list. which is getAt().setDisableSelection(). i'm using sencha so to get the list will be Ext.getCmp('list').getAt(index).setDisableSelection(true). i'm suppose this is how to disable the item selection but it doesn't so any other way to disable a particular item on the list? on sencha. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add a before select event, and return false so it prevents the 'select' event:

```
Ext.getCmp('CheckIn').addBeforeListener('select', function (list, record) {
    if (list.getStore().indexOf(record) == 2) return false;
    else true;
}
```

hope it helps-